# @minLength & @maxLength for securestring are causing problems when running `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment`

Tags: .net, windows, azure, powershell, azure-bicep

I'm receiving the following error message:

> New-AzResourceGroupDeployment: Cannot validate argument on parameter
> 'adminPassword'. The ValidateLength attribute cannot be applied to a
> parameter that is not a string or string[] parameter. Make the
> parameter a string or string[] parameter.

This happens when I run a [bicep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/overview) template containing the following code:

```
@description('MyDescription')
@minLength(12)
@maxLength(123)
@secure()
param adminPassword string
```

I'm running `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` and it prompts me for `adminPassword`. When I enter it in the command prompt (interactively), I receive the error. Yes, I'm entering more than 13 characters in my password.

Removing `@minLength` and `@maxLength` lines helps.

I see that there is a closed issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/8770.

But what's the actual problem? Is this a bug in the bicep script? Or is this a problem in Azure PowerShell / Bicep?

PS Reproducible on Windows and macOS with https://github.com/joshua-a-lucas/BlueTeamLab

Comment: It appears that MS has reopened the bug (ticket) 20 minutes ago: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/8770#event-8168026944

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our product team confirmed that adding the **character length limit to secure string in bicep is not supported** as of now and they are working on a fix for this you can refer to this git hub issue for the status on [fix](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/8770#event-8168026944).

Character length limitation to secure string is supported in ARM templates.